# Regular expression to match the exact suffix

Tags: regex

I am trying to match to a specific suffix only----for example only ends with **".suffix"**: "*me.suffix*" matches, but "*me.suffix.1234*" should not match.

I tried the following expression, but it does not work.

```
.+\.suffix(?!.)
```

Any ideas?  How to only match to a string that does not followed by anything except line break?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want the match to be: a whole line, all text that comes before it? Just one character that comes before it? Including/excluding the suffix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most regular expression engines allow for a "multiline" flag which allows the `$` character to match the end of any line, whether that be a newline or the end of the string. How to enable this varies between engines. For `grep` and related shell commands, this is the default behavior. In JavaScript and PCRE, the `m` flag can be added after the delimiters to enable it, and in Java, a `Pattern` can be compiled with the `MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: Thank you!   Sorry my initial question is not correct and I just edited it.  I need the regexp to match to a string that does not followed by anything except line break.

Comment: Should work with the updated question now. And now I see why `(?!.)` didn't work.

Comment: Now it works!  I wonder why my original (?!.) does not work?  Does it mean look ahead not to follow by any character except new line?

Answer (score 3):

With the multi-line modifier, you'll match line by line:

```
/^.+\.suffix$/gm
```

[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2eU0/1)